# How to "Take Priority" of Audio Playback?

Tags: swift, audio

I have an audio-playback app that crashes when returning from another audio-playing app when the user attempts to re-start playback.  My app works great on it's own and will handle background playback, etc; however when returning from Spotify-like apps it crashes when it starts it's own playback.

I'm guessing there's some sort of "priority" of audio that I should be handling?  And taking that priority "back" from whatever audio app previously had it?  Just looking for a direction to start looking....thanks!

Backtrace:

- thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  frame #0: 0x00000001be4fdec4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
  frame #1: 0x00000001be41d724 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 216
  frame #2: 0x00000001be36d844 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 100
  frame #3: 0x00000001be4c67d4 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 128
  frame #4: 0x00000001be4c69c4 libc++abi.dylib`demangling_terminate_handler() + 296
  frame #5: 0x00000001be42e258 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 124
  frame #6: 0x00000001be4d3304 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
  frame #7: 0x00000001be4d2ed8 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 144
  frame #8: 0x00000001be42e158 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
  frame #9: 0x00000001be67eb4c CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 576
  frame #10: 0x00000001c861f328 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 104
  frame #11: 0x00000001c278c63c UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1936
  frame #12: 0x00000001047c0e78 Sequencer`main at AppDelegate.swift:23:7

  - frame #13: 0x00000001be508360 libdyld.dylib`start + 4

Comment: Do you have a backtrace?

Comment: @marko Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I seem to keep getting "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'player started when in a disconnected state'".  I'm running AudioKit with a sequencer and sampler.

Comment: You have an uncaught exception. Set a breakpoint on "exceptions".